# Sum of all the rows in R without duplicates

Tags: r

I have a large data frame. I need to find the sum of all the rows of a particular column but with duplicate items counted only once. For example,

Consider the following data frame:

```
z = data.frame(id = c(16249, 16249, 16250, 16251), value = c(1, 1, 2, 3))

   id     value
1 16249     1
2 16249     1
3 16250     2
4 16251     3
```

I need to find the sum of all the rows for the column "value" but with duplicate "id" counted only once. So, in the above example, the answer should be: 1+2+3 = 6 (corresponding to id 16249, 16250 and 16251).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `?duplicated`:

```
sum(with(z, value[!duplicated(id)]))
```

Comment: @PrakharMehrotra then please consider upvoting/marking this as the accepted answer by pressing the green check mark so this question no longer appears as unanswered. Thanks!.

Comment: What if a given `id` has two different `value`s associated with it? How does one know which one to pick.  Conversely, do two different `id`s ever have the same value?   If they don't, then `sum(unique(z[2]))` will suffice.